# Upper bound for the dimension of a singularity locus

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, singularity-theory

I am investigating the singularities of a manifold defined as follows,
$$
M =\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, |\, g_1(x)=u_1, \cdots, g_p(x)=u_p\}
$$
where $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,\cdots,p$ are homogeneous polynomials and $u_i$ are constants and $n > p$. 
The partial derivatives $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$ are linear independent and homogeneous polynomials  for all $1\leq i\leq p$ and $1\leq j \leq n$.

Let $Sing^{(n)}(g_1, \cdots, g_p)$ be the locus on $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the gradients $\nabla g_i$ are linearly dependent, more precisely
$$
Sing^{(n)}(g_1, \cdots, g_p) =\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n| \mbox{It exist } \{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^p \subset \mathbb{R} \mbox{ such that } \sum_i \alpha_i \nabla g_i(x)=0\}
$$
I am interested to bound the dimension of  $Sing^{(n)}(g_1, \cdots, g_p)$.
One trivial bound for $dim(Sing^{(n)}(g_1, \cdots, g_p))$ is $n-1$, but I think that it is possible to find better upper bounds due to the linear independence of $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$

Some of you have an idea how to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$ are linearly independent*"? The vectors $\left(\frac{\partial g_i(x)}{\partial x_j}\right)_i\in \mathbb{R}^p$ cannot be linearly independent, because $n>p$ and the vectors $\left(\frac{\partial g_i(x)}{\partial x_j}\right)_j\in \mathbb{R}^n$ correspond to the gradients $\nabla g_1(x),...,\nabla g_p(x)$, so if they were linearly independent, there would be no singular set.

Comment: I mean the second case $\frac{\partial g_i(x)}{\partial x_j} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The polynomials  $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}$ are linearly independent but it can exist  a zero-measure region $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where the evaluation of these polynomials $\frac{\partial g_i(x)}{\partial x_j} \in A$ yields linearly dependent vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I interested to bound the dimension of $A$.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure, if I understand the setting. I do understand that you want to consider linear independence as members of the vector space of polynomials. Then you could ask the $n\times p$ Polynomials $\partial g_i /\partial x_j \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ to be linearly independent, or you could ask that for each $i$ the $p$ Polynomials $\partial g_i /\partial x_j \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ are linearly independent or vice versa. Whatever it is, I suggest to state this clearly in your question.

Comment: The question is still not phrased clearly. The partial derivatives $\partial g_i/\partial x_j$ are *scalar functions*. We've stipulated that the *vectors* $\nabla g_i$ are linearly dependent on the locus in question. So what linear *independence* are you talking about?

Comment: I updated the question. The polynomials $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x}$ are linearly independent but not necessarly the gradients $\nabla g_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ evaluated at some point $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent. I am interested to bound the dimension of the set of points where the gradients $\nabla g_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are not linearly independent.